# Single Application for both "SOAP over JMS" and "SOAP over HTTPS"

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, ear

I have 2 EAR application one is based on "SOAP over JMS" and the other one is based on "SOAP over HTTPS",
now the business requirement is they need both the applications,
but as a result there are lot of duplicate codes spread across both the projects
Is there a solution , in which both the application be combined in a single application and duplication is avoided
(both  have only difference in their WSDL file, and all the java classes are same)
please provide a approach in some detail as to how to tackle this problem

Comment: It depends which server you are using. This is now a server issue rather than implementation.

Comment: both are deployed over websphere application server